# How does the clang implement the weak ptr?

Tags: clang, weak-references

```
- (void)test
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf test];
}
```

compile to

```
static void _I_Foo_test(Foo * self, SEL _cmd) {
 __attribute__((objc_ownership(weak))) typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
 ((void (*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)((id)weakSelf, sel_registerName("test"));
}
```

in objective-c.

The weakptr is provided by the compiler rather than some library like `std::share_ptr` in c++.

How does the compiler implement the weak ptr, will it be something like this.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.weakRef = nil;
    ...
}

-(void)test
{
    self.weakRef = new WeakRef(self);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak pointers in Objective-C are provided by the objc runtime which is a library as well. Accessing the content of a weak pointer is done by [`objc_loadWeak()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418693-objc_loadweak?language=objc) for instance. The clang documentation about [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) explains the details.